# Equivalent Definition Using Limit of Continuity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Definition** : Note that $f: {\bf R}\rightarrow {\bf R}$ is continuous at $x_0$
  if $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x)= f(x_0)$$ And $f$ is continuous
  on $(a,b)$ if $f$ is continuous at any $x_0\in (a,b)$.

I want to know whether or not the following is true :

> $f: {\bf R}\rightarrow {\bf R}$ is continuous at $x_0$ iff there
>    exists $\varepsilon >0$ s.t. $f$ is continuous on $(x_0-
>  \varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon )$.

**Try** : $\Leftarrow$-part is clear. If there exists no such $\varepsilon
>0$, then WLOG, there exists a sequence $x_n > x_0$ s.t. $ x_n (> x_{n+1}) \rightarrow
x_0$ and $f$ is not continuous at $x_n$. But I can not proceed more.
Thank you.

Comment: If $\epsilon>0$ such that $f$ is continuous on the open interval $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$ then $f$ must be continuous at $x_0$ since it is contained in that open interval.

Comment: Yes you're right. So the converse is a problem.

Comment: I see : the converse is not true : For example, $f(q)=q,\ q\in {\bf Q}$ and $f(r)=-r,\ r\in {\bf R}-{\bf Q}$ Then $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Yes, you're correct as your example shows a function that is continuous at $0$ but is not continuous on any neighborhood of $0$ (or anywhere else!).  Good counter examples are always useful.

Comment: @SKLee: I say you may instead ask when we have the equivalence under consideration. :)